# jquery disable click until animation is fully complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, click, bind

i want to disable click function untill every code in it; initialized and completed.

i read these articles and tried what they said but cant make it happen:
[event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)
+ 
[Best way to remove an event handler in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209029/best-way-to-remove-an-event-handler-in-jquery)
+
[jQuery - Disable Click until all chained animations are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271828/jquery-disable-click-until-all-chained-animations-are-complete)

i prepared simple example for this question:

[This is DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aw39W/22/)

html

```
<div class="ele">1</div>
<div class="ele">2</div>
<div class="ele">3</div>
```

​

jQuery

```
$('.ele').click(function() {

    if ( !$('.ele').is(':animated') ) {//this works too but;
                         //is:animate duration returns = 2000 but need to be 4000
        $('.ele').stop().animate({'top':'0px'},2000);
        $(this).stop().animate({'top':'100px'},4000);
    } 
    return false;
});
​
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use on() and off() to turn the click function on/off :

```
$('.ele').on('click', animateEle);

function animateEle(e) {
    $('.ele').stop().animate({'top':'0px'},2000);
    $(e.target).off('click').stop().animate({'top':'100px'},4000, function() {
        $(e.target).on('click', animateEle);
    });
}​
```

**[DEMONSTRATION](http://jsfiddle.net/UJG6P/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var exec_a1 = true, exec_a2 = true;
$('.ele').click(function() {
    if (exec_a1 && exec_a2) {
        exec_a1 = false;
        exec_a2 = false;

        $('.ele').stop().animate({'top': '0px'}, 2000, function() {
            exec_a1 = true;
        });
        $(this).stop().animate({'top': '100px'}, 4000, function() {
            exec_a2 = true;
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```