# how to make .hover() works with.on()?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dynamic HTML content

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Hover Text
    </div>
</div>
```

when I try to hover "hover text" inside child element with this code it doesn't work.

```
$("#parent").on('hover', '.child', function()
{
    alert("Hello");
});
```

this code neither

```
$('#parent').on('hover', '.child', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

I use jq vs 1.10.2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make jQuery 1.7 .on() hover?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541754/how-to-make-jquery-1-7-on-hover) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827095/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-on-and-hover

Comment: thank you, that's helpful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events with `on()`.
Here is example:

```
$(function(){
    $("#parent").on({
        mouseenter : function(e){
            alert("Mouse enter");
        },
        mouseleave : function(e){
            alert("Mouse leave");
        }
    }, ".child");
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/2XG9j/

Answer (score 3):

If the entire `div#parent` block is dynamically generated, you may need to bind your `hover` listener to the document itself, as shown below.

Also, I suggest using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` listeners, as the `hover` shorthand was removed in jQuery 1.9.

> Deprecated in jQuery 1.8, removed in 1.9: The name "hover" used as a
>   shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave".

Here's my sample:

```
jQuery(document).on('mouseenter', '#parent .child', function (e) {
    jQuery(this).css('backgroundColor','#F00');
}).on('mouseleave', '#parent .child', function (e) {
    jQuery(this).css('backgroundColor','#FFF');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UX8z5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. You can use it to simply apply behavior to an element during the time the mouse is within the element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#parent .child').hover(function(){
    alert("Hello");
   });
});
```

[Try in .hover() in Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8DDW/1/)

You can also use [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) event.

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '#parent .child', function(){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

[Try mouseover event handler fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8DDW/)

But here the best practice is bind `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events with event delegation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#parent').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            alert('Hello');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            alert('bye..!!!');
        }
    }, ".child");
});
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K8DDW/3/)