# Disabling animations in jQuery while one animation executes

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a multiple jQuery animations applied on the same element or a group of similar elements. In order to ensur that there are no conflicts and multiple animations at the same time, I want to ensure that while animation A executes, no other animations that apply on the same element should execute as well. However once the animation A has executed, all other animations on the same element are enabled again. This applies to all animations on a single element.

How can I ensure this ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: `if (!$(elem).is(':animated'))` in your animation functions to make sure the element is'nt already animated.

Comment: here is similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283341/jquery-disable-click-until-animation-is-fully-complete