# Disable click event until animation completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my game I have a grid populated with words. To spell the words the user has to click on the letters on the side called "drag". When a letter is clicked it animates into position on the grid.

The problem I am having is that the user can click letters rapidly, which crashes the program. To solve this I want to disable the click events until the animation completes.

In the past I have used a `setTimeOut` function before but it is not a reliable method as the timing all depends on browser speeds.

Here is the click event:

```
$('.drag').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $('.highlight-problem .drop-box:not(.occupied):first');
    var targetPos = target.parents('td').position();
    console.log(targetPos);
    var currentPos = $(this).offset();
    var b = $(this);
    if (target.length) {
        target.addClass("occupied");
        $(".occupied").parent(".flip-wrapper").addClass("flipped");
        var clonedObject = b.clone()
        if (b.data("letter") == target.parents('td').data("letter")) {
            clonedObject.addClass("right-letter");
            target.addClass('right-letter');
            setTimeout(function () {
                hitSound.play();
            }, 550);
        } else {
            clonedObject.addClass("wrong-letter");
            target.addClass('wrong-letter');
            setTimeout(function () {
                missSound.play();
            }, 550);
        }
        clonedObject.appendTo("table").css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: currentPos.top,
            left: currentPos.left
        }).stop().animate({
            top: targetPos.top,
            left: targetPos.left
        }, "slow", function () {
            $(this).prop('disabled', false).css({
                top: 0,
                left: 0
            }).appendTo(target);
            var spellWord = $('.highlight-problem .drop-box');
            if (!spellWord.filter(':not(.occupied)').length) {
                var wordIsCorrect = 0;
                spellWord.each(function () {
                    if ($(this).parents('td').data("letter") == $(this).find("div").data("letter")) {
                        console.log('letter is: ' + $(this).find("div").data("letter"))
                        wordIsCorrect++;
                    }
                });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Disable Click until all chained animations are complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271828/jquery-disable-click-until-all-chained-animations-are-complete) **API** `.is(':animated')` **or** `$(':animated').length` might help! `:)`

Comment: how about displaying a loading spinner till the animation completes?

Comment: create a variable which is set at the end of the animation and wrap the functions which runs on click in an if statement which checks if the variable has been set and only runs if it has.

Comment: I don't think it is that similar, else I would have used it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### You can do it in simple 3 steps.

1. Declare a global variable called `animationComplete` and set it to `false`.

   ```
   var animationComplete = false;
   ```
2. In your `.animate({...});` function, toggle the value after the animation is complete.

   ```
   .animate({
       top: targetPos.top,
       left: targetPos.left
   }, "slow", function () {
       ...
       animationComplete = true;
   });
   ```
3. Check for the completeness using the global variable.

   ```
   if (animationComplete)
   {
       // Do something!
   }
   ```

#### Full Code

**JavaScript**

```
animationComplete = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
    animationComplete = false;
    $(".background").animate({
        height: 50,
        width: 50
    }, 10000, function(){
        animationComplete = true;
    });
    $("button").click(function(){
        if (animationComplete)
            $(".background").animate({
                height: 200,
                width: 200
            }, 10000, function(){
                animationComplete = false;
            });
        else
            alert("Please wait till the animation is complete!");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="background"></div>
<button>Click me!</button>​
```

**CSS**

```
.background {background: red;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KAryP/

#### Fiddle for your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/94/

Comment: Could you show it in relation to my code. Can't seem to get it working @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Okay, can I get your full code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something?

Comment: @Milo-J What am I supposed to drag to where? Nothing is happening when I try to drag! :(

Comment: Sorry its click event not drag. At the moment there is no pictures to help but it you click rapidly you will see the error @Praveen Kumar

Comment: I am getting `null` in my console. Not able to perform any action @Milo-J.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19144/discussion-between-milo-j-and-praveen-kumar)

Comment: @Milo-J I have added the fiddle in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't test code atm, but checking if the element is not animated within click function should do

```
if(!$('selector:animated')){


}
```