# I want to prevent a second click from firing until an animation is complete using bind and unbind but it isnt working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent a second click from firing until an animation is complete.

```
$('#moveDown').click(function(){
  var currentPos = parseInt($('#blog-slider').css('top'));
  if (currentPos < 0) {
    $('#moveDown').unbind('click');
    $('#blog-slider').animate({'top': currentPos + 140},500, function() {
      $('#moveDown').bind('click');
    });
  }
});
```

Unbind is working fine, but it is not rebinding when the animation is complete, so the animation will only run once.

I did look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271828/jquery-disable-click-until-all-chained-animations-are-complete) but this only confirms that "bind" and "unbind" is the way to get the functionality I need and I still don't understand why it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('#moveDown').bind('click')` just triggers a click, unless you bind a function that does something.

One technique is to set and unset a `.data` variable on the element, and check if it's set or not:

```
$('#moveDown').click(function(){
    if (!$('#moveDown').data('clicked')) {
        $('#moveDown').data('clicked',true);
        var currentPos = parseInt($('#blog-slider').css('top'),10); // always use a radix
        if (currentPos < 0) {
            $('#blog-slider').animate({'top': currentPos + 140},500, function() {
                $('#moveDown').data('clicked',false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but is there a way to rebind the click envent? I tried naming the function and binding click to the name of the function but that seems to make it try to run twice. However using "data" does solve the problem.

Comment: Just don't unbind it in the first place. You don't really want to anyway, you just want to prevent it from running.

Comment: Alright I will keep that in mind and research why that is. Thanks!